# Footer Semantic UI

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Hi this is my first time using semantic-ui framework & I have some problem with footer. I want to make footer to always stick in the bottom of page (not fixed).

this is the simple html of mine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="ui borderless menu">
    </nav>

    <div class="desc">
    </div>

    <div class="ui container">
    </div>

    <div class="ui container">
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying use this css:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

but it doesn't work, it just work when the height of page is less than 100% of the monitor height, when it's height have more than 100% of monitor height the footer will float like this:

[image: screenshot]

I also already change the css body with this:
    body {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

but still doesn't work, anyone can help?

This is the full code, I made a long list table so you would know when you click the filter it will push the table down and the footer will mess.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #696F84;
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.item {
  color: #696F84 !important;
}
.logo {
  margin-right: 7px !important;
}
.company {
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #515151;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.desc {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #757575;
}
#filter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #212121;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.1.6/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.1.6/semantic.min.js"></script>

<nav class="ui borderless menu">
  <div class="header item">
    <img class="logo" src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    <div class="company">Company Name</div>
  </div>
  <!-- end left menu -->

</nav>
<!-- end navbar -->

<div>
  <div class="ui container">
    <p>"Description here | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard."</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end description -->

<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui styled accordion" id="filter">
    <div class="title">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      Filter
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="four wide column" id="radio">
          <div class="ui form">
            <div class="grouped fields">
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                  <input type="radio" name="size" value="small">
                  <label>Small</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                  <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium">
                  <label>Medium</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                  <input type="radio" name="size" value="large">
                  <label>Large</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                  <input type="radio" name="size" value="x-large">
                  <label>X-Large</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end grouped fields -->
          </div>
          <!-- end form -->
        </div>
        <!-- end radio -->
        <div class="four wide column" id="checkbox">
          <div class="ui form">
            <div class="grouped fields">
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="small">
                  <label>Red</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="medium">
                  <label>Orange</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="large">
                  <label>Green</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="x-large">
                  <label>Blue</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end grouped fields -->
          </div>
          <!-- end form -->
        </div>
        <!-- end checkbox -->
        <div class="eight wide column" id="input">
          <div class="ui form">
            <div class="grouped fields">
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui labeled input">
                  <div class="ui label">
                    Name
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="your name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                  <input type="hidden" name="gender">
                  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                  <div class="default text">Gender</div>
                  <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end grouped fields -->
          </div>
          <!-- end form -->
        </div>
        <!-- end input -->
      </div>
      <!-- end grid -->
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
  </div>
  <!-- end accordion -->

  <table class="ui blue celled striped compact table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="collapsing">No</th>
        <th>Food</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Calories</th>
        <th>Protein</th>
        <th class="center aligned collapsing">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">1</td>
        <td>Apples</td>
        <td>Ap</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">2</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>Or</td>
        <td>310</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">3</td>
        <td>Mango</td>
        <td>Mg</td>
        <td>360</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- end table -->
</div>
<!-- end container -->

<footer class="footer">
  Micro Tech 2015. All Rights Reserved
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just remove `position: absolute`? What you want, is the normal flow of the elements anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a warp `div` like below

```
<div class="main">
  .......
</div>

<div class="footer">
 ......
</div>
```

and set `css`

```
.main{min-height:100%; 
      padding-bottom:60px; 
      box-sizing:border-box;}
.footer {
  background-color: #212121;
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: 0;  remove this */
  margin-top: -50px; /* add this */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #696F84;
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.item {
  color: #696F84 !important;
}
.logo {
  margin-right: 7px !important;
}
.company {
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #515151;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.desc {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #757575;
}
#filter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.main{min-height:100%; padding-bottom:60px; box-sizing:border-box;}
.footer {
  background-color: #212121;
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: 0;  remove this */
  margin-top: -50px; /* add this */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.1.6/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.1.6/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<nav class="ui borderless menu">
  <div class="header item">
    <img class="logo" src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    <div class="company">Company Name</div>
  </div>
  <!-- end left menu -->

</nav>
<!-- end navbar -->

<div>
  <div class="ui container">
    <p>"Description here | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard."</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end description -->

<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui styled accordion" id="filter">
    <div class="title">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      Filter
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="four wide column" id="radio">
          <div class="ui form">
            <div class="grouped fields">
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                  <input type="radio" name="size" value="small">
                  <label>Small</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                  <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium">
                  <label>Medium</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                  <input type="radio" name="size" value="large">
                  <label>Large</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                  <input type="radio" name="size" value="x-large">
                  <label>X-Large</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end grouped fields -->
          </div>
          <!-- end form -->
        </div>
        <!-- end radio -->
        <div class="four wide column" id="checkbox">
          <div class="ui form">
            <div class="grouped fields">
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="small">
                  <label>Red</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="medium">
                  <label>Orange</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="large">
                  <label>Green</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="x-large">
                  <label>Blue</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end grouped fields -->
          </div>
          <!-- end form -->
        </div>
        <!-- end checkbox -->
        <div class="eight wide column" id="input">
          <div class="ui form">
            <div class="grouped fields">
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui labeled input">
                  <div class="ui label">
                    Name
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="your name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                  <input type="hidden" name="gender">
                  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                  <div class="default text">Gender</div>
                  <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end grouped fields -->
          </div>
          <!-- end form -->
        </div>
        <!-- end input -->
      </div>
      <!-- end grid -->
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
  </div>
  <!-- end accordion -->

  <table class="ui blue celled striped compact table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="collapsing">No</th>
        <th>Food</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Calories</th>
        <th>Protein</th>
        <th class="center aligned collapsing">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">1</td>
        <td>Apples</td>
        <td>Ap</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">2</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>Or</td>
        <td>310</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">3</td>
        <td>Mango</td>
        <td>Mg</td>
        <td>360</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="collapsing">4</td>
        <td>Grape</td>
        <td>Gr</td>
        <td>210</td>
        <td>0g</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- end table -->
</div>
<!-- end container -->
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  Micro Tech 2015. All Rights Reserved
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I solved it with giving the nav, main, & footer their own height in percent :D. thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

Just set

```
.footer{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
}
```

fixed position in this case is the best way to position your footer always on the bottom.

Comment: as I said in the post: I am not required fixed style bro. I want to the footer stick on bottom page, not in the bottom of  screen/browser window

Answer (score 0):

*OP stated he does not want a fixed footer*

This is what is causing your issue:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

`height` should not be set for your footer to be at the bottom (it comes from `semantic.min.css`).

To cancel this, add this at the beginning of your CSS stylesheet (`!important` is needed here to override the value set by the other stylesheet, but you should otherwise **avoid** using it at all costs):

```
body, html {
  height: auto!important;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="ui borderless menu">
</nav>

<div class="desc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div class="ui container">
</div>

<div class="ui container">
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  some footer at the bottom
</footer>
```

Comment: !important is just my experiment because I am desperate can't make it stick to bottom, and your suggestion still doesn't work sir.. :(

Comment: so what is the solution to make it stick at bottom?

Comment: Without the whole page, I cannot really understand if anything else is preventing the footer to stay at the bottom. But in my *extremely simplified* example it works.

Comment: there I update the post with full code, try to go fullpage when running snippet then you will see my problem :(